# code igniter question: problem with passing variable to a view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am a newbie with CodeIgniter (2.03), and I have the following problem:

Here is my main template (view):

```
<?php $this->load->view('backOffice/bo_header_in'); ?>

<?php $this->load->view($bo_main_content); ?>

<?php $this->load->view('backOffice/bo_footer_in'); ?>
```

Here is my model:

```
<?php

class Back_office_users extends CI_Model 
{

  public function getAllUsers () 
  {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users");

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
      foreach ($query->result() as $rows) {
        $users[] = $rows;
      }
      return $users; 
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my controler:

```
<?php

class Dashboard extends CI_Controller 
{

  public function __construct() 
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->is_logged_in();
  }

  public function index () 
  {   
    $this->load->model('back_office_users');
    $users['rows'] = $this->back_office_users->getAllUsers();

    $data['bo_main_content'] = "backOffice/dashboard";

    $this->load->view('backOffice/bo_template_in', $data, $users);

   // if I pass the variable like this it works just fine...
   //$this->load->view('backOffice/users', $users);
  }

  public function is_logged_in()
  {
    $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
    if (!isset($is_logged_in) || ($is_logged_in != true)) {
      $this->accessdenied();   
    }
  }

  public function accessdenied () 
  {    
    $data['bo_main_content'] = 'backOffice/accessdenied';
    $this->load->view('backOffice/bo_template', $data);
  }

  public function logout () 
  {    
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect('backOffice/index');
  }
}
```

And the dashboard view is like this:

```
<?php
  print_r($users);
?>
```

I am getting the following error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: users
>
> Filename: backOffice/dashboard.php
>
> Line Number: 9

Can anyone shed some light how can I resolve this? I create another view without use of the template, and it print the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not passing the `$users` variable to the second (nested) view.

I'd suggest adding `$users` to the `$data` array, and then in the first view pass the `$users` array to the embedded view. So, in your controller:

```
public function index () {

  /* stuff... */

  $data['users']['rows'] = $this->back_office_users->getAllUsers();

  $data['bo_main_content'] = "backOffice/dashboard";

  /* stuff... */

  $this->load->view('backOffice/bo_template_in', $data);
}
```

Then in the main view:

```
<?php $this->load->view($bo_main_content, $users); ?>
```

Then in the dashboard view:

```
<?php
  print_r($rows);
?>
```

This is because in the main view, as you know, CodeIgniter transforms all elements of `$data` in to variables, so we'll end up with the `$users` variables. `$users` is an array containing `rows`, so when we pass `$users` to the *second* view, the second view transforms all elements of `$users` in to view variables, hence we now have access to `$row`.

Comment: Thanks Alex.

Not only the code works but from your answer, I realize my mistake.

Thanks for your time and for sharing your valuable knowledge.

Regards, Zoreli